# Apache Spark compile failed while installing Netty

Tags: apache-spark

We untar `spark-0.9.0-incubating.tgz` and trying to build it for use with Yarn.

```
SPARK_HADOOP_VERSION=2.0.0-cdh4.6.0 SPARK_YARN=true sbt/sbt assembly
```

...
[info] Resolving io.netty#netty-all;4.0.13.Final ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.13.Final/netty-all-4.0.13.Final.pom
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.13.Final/netty-all-4.0.13.Final.pom
...

If I just cut-paste the url into a browser, I get:

```
404 - ItemNotFoundException

Retrieval of /io/netty/netty-all/4.0.13.Final/netty-all-4.0.13.Final.pom from M2Repository(id=snapshots) is forbidden by repository policy SNAPSHOT.

org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.ItemNotFoundException: Retrieval of /io/netty/netty-all/4.0.13.Final/netty-all-4.0.13.Final.pom from M2Repository(id=snapshots) is forbidden by repository policy SNAPSHOT.
    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.maven.AbstractMavenRepository.doRetrieveItem(AbstractMavenRepository.java:380)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.maven.maven2.M2Repository.doRetrieveItem(M2Repository.java:396)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.repository.AbstractRepository.retrieveItem(AbstractRepository.java:765)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.repository.AbstractRepository.retrieveItem(AbstractRepository.java:608)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.router.DefaultRepositoryRouter.retrieveItem(DefaultRepositoryRouter.java:155)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.web.content.NexusContentServlet.doGet(NexusContentServlet.java:359)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.web.content.NexusContentServlet.service(NexusContentServlet.java:331)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
```

I have seen this reported in a number of places but no solution. Is this error because we are behind a corporate firewall, or is this due to something else? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I had proxy set as environment variables, but it appears they are not being picked up. Adding them in sbt directly worked for me.

Edit $SPARK_HOME/sbt/sbt

For example,

EXTRA_ARGS="-Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy.mycompany.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxySet=true -Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy.mycompany.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Dftp.proxySet=true -Dftp.proxyHost=myproxy.mycompany.com -Dftp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=mydomain -Dhttps.nonProxyHosts=mydomain -Dftp.nonProxyHosts=mydomain"